# How to create an integer array on RHS of an rule in CLIPS

Tags: clips

how can we create an integer array on rhs side of clips..

I tried

```
 (bind ?new_ints (numbers ?new_count ?new_bad_count ?new_good_count))
```

The idea is that new_count, new_bad_count, new_good_count should go into new_ints.

and it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no primitive data type in CLIPS for multi-dimensional arrays. You can use a multifield value to represent one-dimensional arrays:

```
CLIPS> (bind ?array (create$ 1 2 3))
(1 2 3)
CLIPS> (nth$ 3 ?array)
3
CLIPS> (length$ ?array)
3
CLIPS>
```